# Process memory does not increase after creating an object?

Tags: c#, debugging, memory, process

I am currently trying to understand how the memory-properties like WorkingSet64, PagedMemorySize64 and so on. I have written a small programm that shall debug the memory consumption for its own process.

There are three classes:

A DTO to persist a memory dump:

```
public class ProcessDTO
{
    public ProcessDTO(long workingSet64, long privateMemorySize64, long pagedSystemMemorySize64, long pagedMemorySize64)
    {
        WorkingSet64 = workingSet64;
        PrivateMemorySize64 = privateMemorySize64;
        PagedSystemMemorySize64 = pagedSystemMemorySize64;
        PagedMemorySize64 = pagedMemorySize64;
    }

    public long WorkingSet64 { get; private set; }
    public long PrivateMemorySize64 { get; private set; }
    public long PagedSystemMemorySize64 { get; private set; }
    public long PagedMemorySize64 { get; private set; }
}
```

A Process reader, that first forces the GC to run and then creates a memory dump:

```
internal class ProcessDumper
{
    public ProcessDTO GetProcessDump(Process process)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        var workingSet64 = process.WorkingSet64;
        var privateMemorySize64 = process.PrivateMemorySize64;
        var pagedSystemMemorySize64 = process.PagedSystemMemorySize64;
        var pagedMemorySize64 = process.PagedMemorySize64;

        var result = new ProcessDTO(workingSet64, privateMemorySize64, pagedSystemMemorySize64, pagedMemorySize64);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And finally my console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processDumper = new ProcessDumper();
        var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        var before = processDumper.GetProcessDump(process);
        Console.WriteLine("[WS64] Before: {0} bytes", before.WorkingSet64);
        Console.WriteLine("[priv64] Before: {0} bytes", before.PrivateMemorySize64);
        Console.WriteLine("[PMS64] Before: {0} bytes", before.PagedMemorySize64);
        Console.WriteLine("[PSMS64] Before: {0} bytes", before.PagedSystemMemorySize64);

        Console.WriteLine();
        var foo = new byte[]
        {
            0x10, 0x99, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10,
            0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10,
            0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10,
            0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10,
            0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10,
            0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10,
            0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10,
            0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10,
            0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x04, 0x10,
            0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10,
        };
        var max = foo.Max();
        Console.WriteLine("Just to do something with my object... max is {0}", max);

        var after = processDumper.GetProcessDump(process);

        var min = foo.Min();
        Console.WriteLine("Just to do something with my object... min is {0}", min);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("[WS64] After:  {0} bytes", after.WorkingSet64);
        Console.WriteLine("[priv64] After:  {0} bytes", after.PrivateMemorySize64);
        Console.WriteLine("[PMS64] After:  {0} bytes", after.PagedMemorySize64);
        Console.WriteLine("[PSMS64] After:  {0} bytes", after.PagedSystemMemorySize64);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("[WS64] Diff:   {0} bytes", (after.WorkingSet64 - before.WorkingSet64));
        Console.WriteLine("[priv64] Diff:   {0} bytes", (after.PrivateMemorySize64 - before.PrivateMemorySize64));
        Console.WriteLine("[PMS64] Diff:   {0} bytes", (after.PagedMemorySize64 - before.PagedMemorySize64));
        Console.WriteLine("[PSMS64] Diff:   {0} bytes", (after.PagedSystemMemorySize64 - before.PagedSystemMemorySize64));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Now the fun part begins. I assumed, that the memory increased between `before` and `after` - but the memory consumption is *always* the same.

```
[WS64] Diff:   0 bytes
[priv64] Diff:   0 bytes
[PMS64] Diff:   0 bytes
[PSMS64] Diff:   0 bytes
```

What am I missing here? I have also tried to move the output of the `before`, `after` and `diff` to the very bottom so that they are kept in memory while dumping, nevertheless this seems to have no change - Diff is always zero.

Comment: When you start .NET Framework application framework allocates some amount of memory which is then used to allocate all objects you create. It makes memory allocation faster, because it does not require low level interaction with system to allocate small amount of memory when your program is running. Your test project probably does not force the framework to ask system for more memory, and that's why you don't see any difference.

Comment: This makes sense. Is there a possibility to see how much memory is free and has already been allocated?

Comment: @ElGauchooo One great tool is VMMap to see how much the .NET FW *actually* prepares (it shows non-commited memory too, so don't worry, it can be terabytes :D). Another awesome tool is CLRProfiler, which will show you all the real in-memory sizes of all the objects in your application at a given time.

Comment: @Luaan Can i use VMMap or CLRProfiler to read statistics programmatically from my own code? See my other question - this is what i *really* want to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575359/programmatically-find-memory-leaks-in-external-dll-in-c-sharp

Comment: @ElGauchooo You can do that from native code, yes. The question is - why would you want to? If you're loading plugins, load them in a different AppDomain - then you can simply unload the AppDomain and you're done. There's no way to see if a general application has a memory leak (if it were possible, your OS could do it for you :)). Also, you should not be trying to fix issues created by 3rd party providers - that moves all the responsibility on your shoulders. Instead, let people find out themselves that the plugins are written wrong, and let them decide if they want to use them.

Comment: @Luaan Why i am trying to do this is not my decision, it's my companies. ;) It makes sense, because we got many support calls telling us `your framework is buggy` (in 99% it's their fault, not ours - for example due to memory leaks). What i'm currently working on is a test environment, not a productive environment where i want to point out the issues a plugin has.

Comment: @ElGauchooo This is further complicated by the fact that memory management in managed environments (like .NET) is quite complicated. The AppDomain could have 2 GB of memory allocated, but that doesn't mean it has a memory leak (the only need to release memory is if the system is under memory pressure)! And at the same time, your plugin could have just 10 MB allocated, while still taking up 2 GB of memory, and unable to release any (a fragmented heap with pinned objects is a common source of this kind of issue). So - load plugins in a different process or a different AppDomain - best you can do

Comment: @ElGauchooo And that's still just if you only use .NET plugins. But if you allow any DLL, you have no idea what kind of memory management that plugin has. All in all, if you don't want them to crash your process (but can afford to let the plugin itself fail), load the plugins in a different process (you can even set memory limits for each if you really want to, but it's probably a bad idea) or on .NET, a different AppDomain. That means that when the plugin crashes, it doesn't take your application with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that it is not counting the used bytes in a partion of reserved memory, but the size of the reserved memory. Only if all reserved memory (in for example PrivateMemorySize64) in is used, the runtime will allocate more memory for that set.

Answer (score 0):

There was another issue. As i used the same process object created by `var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();`, all properties requested from this object have been the same. Re-creating it for the `after`-dump showed a difference

```
[WS64] Diff:   716800 bytes
[priv64] Diff:   593920 bytes
[PMS64] Diff:   593920 bytes
[PSMS64] Diff:   136 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to call `process.Refresh()` before reading the memory usage stats.